# How to add a recyclerview as a child of another recyclerview

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I have a recylcerView called "Classroom", I'm trying to add an new recylerview called "Assignments" which will be created inside the notes recylerview item. When I click on a recylerview item (classroom) it send me to ClassworkActivity in which the assignments' recyclerview will be added to.

But the problem is that, when I create an assignment, It's displaying in every Classroom (recyclerview item). I want to create an assignment in a specific classroom. For example if I click on "Algebra classroom" and I create an "assignment 1", I want that assignment to be displayed only in Algebra classroom, not in every classroom

**AddClassroomActivity.java**

```
    private void AddClassrooms(String titlesend, String descsend) {

    String id=mDatabase.push().getKey();

    Intent intent = new Intent(AddClassroomActivity.this, ClassworkActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("ClassroomId", id);


    Listdata listdata = new Listdata(id,titlesend, descsend);
    userID = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();

    mDatabase.child("Users").child(userID).child("Classrooms").child(id).setValue(listdata).
            addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                    Toast.makeText(AddClassroomActivity.this, "Classroom Added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ClassroomActivity.class));
                }
            });
}
```

in **ClassworkActivity.java** I tried to retrieve the Classrooms id (child(id)) from AddClassroomActivity like this:

```
String id = getIntent().getExtras().get("ClassroomId").toString();

        firebaseDatabase=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();

        databaseReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference().child("Users").child(userID).child("Classrooms").child(id).child("Assignments");
```

But I get this error:

> Unable to start activity   ComponentInfo{com.example.schoolteacher/com.example.schoolteacher.ClassworkActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference
> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference
> at com.example.schoolteacher.ClassworkActivity.onCreate(ClassworkActivity.java:127)

Comment: Have you checked to see if `id` is null?

Comment: `    Intent intent = new Intent(AddClassroomActivity.this, ClassworkActivity.class);
    notesIntent.putExtra("ClassroomId", id);`

You're creating one intent then putting an extra *on a different intent.* Is that intentional?

Comment: it's a typo, sorry... I edited my question

Comment: Set a breakpoint after `String id=mDatabase.push().getKey();`. Is `id` null?

Comment: What is line 127 of ClassworkActivity? That's where your app is crashing. I'm guessing it's `String id = getIntent().getExtras().get("ClassroomId").toString();`

Comment: Yes it's `String id = getIntent().getExtras().get("ClassroomId").toString();`

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/debug#breakPoints

Comment: I get this after debug : this = {ClassworkActivity@14797} 
 context = null
 databaseReference = null
 firebaseDatabase = null
 list = {ArrayList@14813}  size = 0
 mCurrentUser = {zzn@14806} 
 mFirebaseAuth = {zzl@14814} 
 mFirebaseUser = {zzn@14806} 
 notesAdapter = null

Comment: Looks like you're not setting up Firebase properly. I recommend going through the setup documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/start